# Преобразование массива в в JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Задача: собрать элементы на странице и сделать массив или точнее  JSON  в виде

```
var arr = {
    {3988: {opmerkingen: "", passed: ""}}, 
    {3989: {opmerkingen: "commmmment", passed: "true"}}
}
```

В итоге получилось так:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(item);

arr = [{3988: {opmerkingen: "", passed: ""}}, {3989: {opmerkingen: "commmmment", passed: "true"}}]
```

Как вместо квадратных сделать фигурные скобки?

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь это `object` а не `array` => `var arr = { {3988: {opmerkingen: "", passed: ""}}, {3989: {opmerkingen: "commmmment", passed: "true"}} }`

Comment: а ответ на ваш вопрос прочитать можете тут `https://learn.javascript.ru/object`

Comment: Первый пример не является корректным выражением JavaScript. В JSON у массивов должны быть квадратные скобки

Comment: "Как вместо квадратных сделать фигурные скобки?" - зачем? Продолжайте пробовать объяснить, чего Вы хотите достичь.

Answer (score 2):

Указанный в самом начале формат не является валидным, так как объект не может содержать анонимные свойства:

**Не валидный вариант:**

```
var arr = {
    {3988: {opmerkingen: "", passed: ""}}, 
    {3989: {opmerkingen: "commmmment", passed: "true"}}
}
```

**Валидный вариант:**

```
var arr = {
    "3988": {opmerkingen: "", passed: ""}, 
    "3989": {opmerkingen: "commmmment", passed: "true"}
}
```

При этом элементы получается циклом либо `var elm = arr["3988"];`

Если же вам нужен именно массив объектов тут работает ваш вариант:

> ```
> var arr = []; arr.push(item);
>
> arr = [{3988: {opmerkingen: "", passed: ""}}, {3989: {opmerkingen: "commmmment", passed: "true"}}]
> ```

---

#### Формат JSON

> Данные в формате JSON ([RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)) представляют собой:
>
> JavaScript-объекты { ... } или
> массивы [ ... ] или
> значения одного из
> типов:
>
> - строки в двойных кавычках,
> - число,
> - логическое значение true/false, null.
>
> [Оригинал -> Язык JavaScript -> Некоторые другие возможности](https://learn.javascript.ru/json)

Comment: всем спасибо. но нужно было собрать как ассоциативный массив

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = JSON.stringify([
    {3988: {opmerkingen: "", passed: ""}}, 
    {3989: {opmerkingen: "commmmment", passed: "true"}}
]);
```

это то, что вам нужно